# Make JSON the default format in Resetler?

Tags: php, rest, restler

I'm going through the tutorial examples of Restler here: http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_003_multiformat/readme.html

While it states that:

> First format specified in `Restler::setSupportedFormats` is used as the
>   default format when client does not specify the format.

I find it not true. As while I have:

```
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
$r = new Restler();
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat');
$r->addAPIClass('BMI', '/api/data/bmi');
$r->handle();
```

Which is exactly the same as that of the code given on the example page, but when I access **/api/data/bmi** it's giving XML rather than JSON.

I had to go to **/api/data/bmi.json** to get the JSON format. Ain't **'JsonFormat'** the first parameter for setSupportedFormats() here? Why isn't JSON the default format? How to make it the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have tried calling the api using web browser. Browser sends an accept header where html and xml are accepted that is why xml is rendered by default. Try calling it with no accept header using curl

Comment: I find JSON more readable than XML even in browser. Is there any way to force JSON for browsers as well?

Comment: just add .json extension to the url

Answer (score 0):

I'm always getting JSON output by just putting this line in my index.php:

```php
use Luracast\Restler\Format\JsonFormat;
```